# What are the differences between segues: "show", "show detail", "present modally", "present as popover"?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6, segue

What do the different segues do in Xcode 6?

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25966215/whats-the-difference-between-all-the-selection-segues

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25966215/whats-the-difference-between-all-the-selection-segues

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between all the Selection Segues?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25966215/whats-the-difference-between-all-the-selection-segues)

Answer (score 184, accepted):

> **1. Show** - Pushes the destination view controller onto the navigation stack, moving the source view controller out of the way (destination slides overtop from right to left), providing a back button to navigate back to the source - on all devices.
>
> Example: Navigating inboxes/folders in Mail.
>
> **2. Show Detail** - Replaces the detail/secondary view controller when in a UISplitViewController with no ability to navigate back to the previous view controller.
>
> Example: In Mail on iPad in landscape, tapping an email in the sidebar replaces the view controller on the right to show the new email.
>
> **3. Present Modally** - Presents a view controller in various different ways as defined by the Presentation option, covering up the previous view controller - most commonly used to present a view controller that animates up from the bottom and covers the entire screen on iPhone, but on iPad it's common to present it in a centered box format overtop that darkens the underlying view controller.
>
> Example: Tapping the + button in Calendar on iPhone.
>
> **4. Popover Presentation** - When run on iPad, the destination appears in a small popover, and tapping anywhere outside of this popover will dismiss it. On iPhone, popovers are supported as well but by default if it performs a Popover Presentation segue, it will present the destination view controller modally over the full screen.
>
> Example: Tapping the + button in Calendar on iPad (or iPhone, realizing it is converted to a full screen presentation as opposed to an actual popover).
>
> **5. Custom** - You may implement your own custom segue and have complete control over its appearance and transition.

Comment: **Show** detail: _The default implementation of this method calls the targetViewController(forAction:sender:) method to locate an object in the view controller hierarchy that overrides this method. It then calls the method on that target object, **which displays the view controller in an appropriate way**. If the targetViewController(forAction:sender:) method returns nil, this method uses the window’s root view controller to **present vc modally**._

Comment: Show: What if there is no navigation stack?