# Navigation Controller - Nav Bar not showing on children

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have view controller A and view controller B. A has a seque to B. A is embedded in a Navigation Controller.

The nav bar shows OK on A, however, it isn't showing on B. I'd expect to see see the nav bar and a "< Back" button. Here is my storyboard setup:

[image]

Is there something I have to do to get the nav bar to show up? Thanks!

Comment: Simple question did you add manually the navigation bar in your viewController A or is the embedded navigation bar from UINavigationController?

Comment: @ReinierMelian The navigation bar in ViewController A is from embedding it in a Navigation Controller

Comment: check your second viewController in right properties bar, check for top bar value and tell me what is the current value?

Comment: @ReinierMelian - value is "Inferred"

Comment: What kind of segue are you using?

Comment: @MikeTaverne Ah, I was using Show Detail. Changing to Show fixed it. Not sure the reasoning, nonetheless, thanks for the comment

Comment: Show Detail is not at all the same as Show, nor would it have been appropriate in this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far, I assume the only reason that could let the navigation bar to be hidden is letting the kind of the segue to be *not* a `Show`. From the attached screenshot, it seems that your segue kind is `Show Detail`, if you would change it to `Show` it should be good.

Select the segue and then select the attributes inspector, change the "kind" option to: "Show (e.g. Push)":

[image]

and you should get the expected result.

**Also**

If you would like to know what's the difference between `Show` and `Show Details` segues, you might want to check: [What are the differences between segues: “show”, “show detail”, “present modally”, “present as popover”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26287247/what-are-the-differences-between-segues-show-show-detail-present-modally)