# IOS Simlulator Master-Detail application template

Tags: ios, uitableview, ipad, uiimage

Can someone help me in my Master-detail Application? So my UIImage only covers half of the screen when i open up the tableview on an iPad. Could it be something wrong with my auto layouts or constraints? I need the UIImage to pop up on the details page which is on the left and cover the whole thing.  I also connected the segue push control from my tableview cell to the detail page.[image]

Answer (score 0):

I thhink you meant you want the image on right side. so you should use ShowDetail segue you might want to refer to [this answer by joey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25966215/whats-the-difference-between-all-the-selection-segues)