# dismissViewControllerAnimated close all view controller to root [swift]

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

let's say I've 4 view controller

**page 1** ----showdetail----> **page 2** ----showdetail----> **page 3** ----showdetail----> **page 4**

I want to go back to page 3 from page 4 with `self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)`. It works fine in iOS 9 but it closes all view controller to page 1 when i try it in iOS 8 device

Comment: From where are you calling `dismissViewControllerAnimated `?

Comment: Why you use **showdetail** segue type? You **show** segue type and use following code.
self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)

Comment: **showdetail** segue is kind of replace view controller..

Comment: @showdetail i use 'show' first and i changed to showdetail when i realize the ios 8 's error. okay i'll try it

Comment: Are you using NavigationController? To pop just one view you can do `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to use `Present Modally` segue instead of `Show Detail`. Here there is a good explanation for each kind of segues [What's the difference between all the Selection Segues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25966215/whats-the-difference-between-all-the-selection-segues)