# Manual and Non-Adaptive Manual Segues

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, segue

What is a Manual and Non-Adaptive Manual Segue, and the difference between them? Any explanation in detail will be helpful.

> **Case 1**

[image][image]

> **Case 2**

[image][image]

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_storyboard/Chapters/StoryboardSegue.html

Comment: please stop spamming questions and answers randomly with links to this question. you've already added a bounty. if someone can help they will

Comment: This question is a duplicate of [What's the difference between all the Selection Segues?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25966215/2415822).  I can't vote to close it because of the bounty attached, and a mod flag will be declined since the bounty only has 3 days left.

Comment: I'm not asking about about selection segue i asked about what is Manual and Non-adaptive Manual segue. @JAL

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The non-adaptive manual segues are deprecated and they don't adapt to the screen size and orientation, that's why they are called "non-adaptive".

With iOS 8, the size classes were introduced (Regular and Compact) and the new Adaptive Segues adapt to these, like when you turn your iPhone to landscape orientation, the status bar will disappear and the navbar will shorten in height.

[Adaptive UI in iOS 8: Explained - iMore](http://www.imore.com/adaptive-ui-ios-8-explained)

[What's the difference between all the Selection Segues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25966215/whats-the-difference-between-all-the-selection-segues)