# Can't pass data between view controllers using segues (Xcode 7) (Swift)

Tags: swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, segue, transfer

I have been struggling to pass data between view controllers using segues. I have watched many youtube video tutorials and searched around on forums but I can't figure out why it won't work. I don't get any error messages but when I click the 'Button' the simulator crashes. I would love some help! Thanks!

**Here is the code :**

**ViewController1 :**

```
    import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var textField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        let destViewController : ViewController2 = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewController2

        destViewController.labelText = textField.text!

    }

}
```

**ViewController2 :**

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class ViewController2 : UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var Label: UILabel!

    var labelText : String = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        Label.text = labelText

    }

}
```

**StoryBoard Image :**

[storyboard image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eq95y.png)

Comment: Which line it is crashing?

Comment: @Alife you missed that segue.identifier = " some identifier"

Comment: on your viewController2 try to change this line 
var labelText : String = ""
to this
var labelText : String!   To prevent simulator from crashing try changing this " destViewController.labelText = textField.text!" to this "        destViewController.labelText = textField.text ?? "text field is empty thats why nothing happens" "

Comment: @Shanmugasundharamselvadurai where to i insert the segue identifier?

Comment: @Santosh I get the error 'Thead 1: Signal SIGABRT' in my appDelegate.swift file but i checked all of the connections.

Comment: @NoelCarcases I tried both of the things that you suggested but neither made any change. When I tried your second suggestion, it gave me the error 'Cannot use optional chaining on non-optional value of type String'.

Comment: What the crash logs says in the console ? Are you able to see that logs? When it crashes just click continue, you would be able to see the logs

Comment: @NoelCarcases I couldn't use the will appear method. It said i had to use "," as a separator so I did. It then gave me another error but I don't know what the fix is or what the error message is. Also, I cleaned my project but it still crashes.

Comment: @Santosh **The crash logs :**                                                                       _2016-09-22 18:47:14.192 ViewControllerDataPassingTest[51357:3697272] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.'
*** First throw call stack:_

Comment: On storyboard click on the segue and change the type to detail or embebed, the error indicate that you are not using a navigation controller so push segue will not work for you

Comment: Later I will power on the computer to check but I think modal is fine. I will argument on that later on an answer

Comment: @NoelCarcases Thank you so much! I changed it from Push to Modal and now it works fine!

Comment: I have posted an answer with a link to another question, please note that push and modal segues are deprecated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated on the comment the problem was that you were using a push segue on a UIViewController.

Please note that push and modal segues are deprecated... Please take a look at this post entry and let me know if you have any doubts

[What's the difference between all the Selection Segues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25966215/whats-the-difference-between-all-the-selection-segues)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to enter some text in your label `textField` before tapping the button since you are passing that label's text to next scene by using force unwrap.

```
  destViewController.labelText = textField.text! //here compiler expects that your textField has the value
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a sample project using your same code and didn't get an error. There's nothing wrong with your code.

Try this: Go to your storyboard and check outlets inspector for each view controller and make sure you don't have an outlet to nowhere.

Comment: I checked and didn't find anything. I do get a SIGABRT error though.

Comment: That's the error you normally get with unconnected outlets. All your outlets should have a filled in circle. You should have  2 outlets on ViewController (textField and view) and 2 outlets on ViewController 2 (Label and view).