# Master detail application initial view controller change

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new to ios world and have a question about Master detail application.
Root view is UISplitViewController. I have LoginViewController and want to make it root view and then after button click segue UISplitViewController.
[image]

I tried it but receive error "Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController"

```
AppDelegate.swift


import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UISplitViewControllerDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
//        let splitViewController = window!.rootViewController as! UISplitViewController
//        let navigationController = splitViewController.viewControllers[splitViewController.viewControllers.count-1] as! UINavigationController
//        navigationController.topViewController!.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = splitViewController.displayModeButtonItem
//        splitViewController.delegate = self
        return true
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    }

    // MARK: - Split view

    func splitViewController(_ splitViewController: UISplitViewController, collapseSecondary secondaryViewController:UIViewController, onto primaryViewController:UIViewController) -> Bool {
        guard let secondaryAsNavController = secondaryViewController as? UINavigationController else { return false }
        guard let topAsDetailController = secondaryAsNavController.topViewController as? DetailViewController else { return false }
        if topAsDetailController.detailItem == nil {
            // Return true to indicate that we have handled the collapse by doing nothing; the secondary controller will be discarded.
            return true
        }
        return false
    }

}
```

LoginViewController

```
import UIKit

class LoginViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var TryButton: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        TryButton.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    }

    @IBAction func policiesButtonClick(_ sender: Any) {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://google.com/#q=") else {
            return
        }
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(url)
        } else {
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Comment: use another kind of segue   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25966215/whats-the-difference-between-all-the-selection-segues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to embed your controller with Navigation controller as below :

**Select Navigation controller**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you should add a UINavigationController after mainViewController, and there, set Root and the rest of the navigation. Since SplitViewController is not a NavigationController, he can't make Push's and Pop's.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your root view to **UINavigationController**. The error is clearly saying the same.

> "Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by
>   an instance of UINavigationController"

**SplitViewController** to NavigationControllers the segue is different. It should embed segue not **push** or **pop**. Push and pop segues are only associated with Navigation controllers