# Swift 5. How present or show ViewController on button touch? Without Storyboard (programmatically)

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller

How can I `show()` or `persent()` VC on button touch? What code should I write?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**First, using Storyboards**

If you are working with storyboard. You should connect your button view storyboard.

```
@IBAction fileprivate func handlePresentingView(_ sender: UIButton) {
  let vc = SecondVC() 
  present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

**Second, programmatically**

**1:** If you are working programmatically
in `viewDidLoad` add the following line.

```
    mybutton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handlePresentingVC(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

**2:** Your action method

```
  @objc func handlePresentingVC(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let vc = SecondVC()
    present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
```

> In my example, I'm assuming that you don't have a storyboard file for
>   your `SecondVC` view controller.
>
> If `SecondVC` is connected to a storyboard view controller, you will
>   need to change the instantiation of your `secondVC` object inside of
>   your button's action method.

**1:** Select your SecondVC's view controller in your storyboard.

**2:** Add a Storyboard ID to it.
[image]

**3:** Change your button's action method to the following.

```
  @objc func handlePresentingVC(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let secondVc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondVC") as! SecondVC

    present(secondVc, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
```

**In Swift 5 and iOS 13**

The default modal presentation style is a card. This shows the previous view controller at the top and allows the user to swipe away the presented view controller.

To retain the old style you need to modify the view controller inside of your button's action method like this:

```
secondVc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
```

This is the same for both programmatically created and storyboard created controllers.

Comment: When I use this code, it sent me an Issue: `Attempt to present <EventsOn.EventsViewController: 0x102f5d640> on <EventsOn.LoginViewController: 0x102f5dc50> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!`

Comment: Can you provide your `viewDidLoad` code as well as your button's action method?

Comment: You can try and add the following line in your button's action method:
`secondVc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen`

Comment: what's the difference between `show` and `present`? I understand the difference when it comes to segues, but not with alerts. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25966215/whats-the-difference-between-all-the-selection-segues